# Is Ken Schwaber advocating a platform model in this blog post?

Tags: scrum, safe, nexus

**Context**:  Working as a Developer within an enterprise delivery encompassing a full technology stack across 22 feature teams - very SOA and backend heavy.

As part of the Agile journey for the teams we have moved gradually from SOA and technology platform teams to self-organizing feature teams.

As complexity increased, teams migrated to SAFe and/or Nexus when multiple feature teams combined.

However during some reading I discovered this blog [post](https://kenschwaber.wordpress.com/2015/06/03/what-is-scaling-scrum/) by Ken Schwaber which states

> So you can have hundreds and hundreds of Scrum teams working on the
>   same product area. However, when you have functionality that requires
>   more than nine or so teams you have a choices:
>
> ***Build architectural and platform structures (IOS, API, etc.) that
>   defines how the functionality from each set of Scrum teams must
>   deliver and interoperate.***

Is that a (slim) statement that in enterprise deliveries a platform model works with feature teams bolted on?

I read it as platform teams are the custodians of quality and procedures and (possibly) environments.

Comment: I think what we can assume is he it advocating Waterfall for all Agile projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

The statement just encapsulates Bob Lewis' [oft-repeated trope](http://www.weblog.keepthejointrunning.com/?p=1836):

> To optimize the whole you usually have to sub-optimize the parts.

The post talks about the trade-offs involved in standardization vs. bottom-up architecture as it regards integration between Scrum teams *at scale*. In this case, "at scale" is defined as integration between more than nine teams.

### Analysis

The [full quote](https://kenschwaber.wordpress.com/2015/06/03/what-is-scaling-scrum/) is:

> So you can have hundreds and hundreds of Scrum teams working on the same product area. However, when you have functionality that requires more than nine or so teams you have two choices:
>
> 1. Build architectural and platform structures (IOS, API, etc.) that defines how the functionality from each set of Scrum teams must deliver and interoperate.
> 2. and/or take longer and only do as much as the nine or so teams can do at once. Then do more. Then do more.

In context, all this is saying is that you can't fully integrate at scale with a bottom-up approach except through emergent design. So you either need to provide standards, or accept that it will take longer to integrate projects produced by large numbers of teams.

### Examples

As an example, if you have 50 Scrum teams working on web projects, they can **integrate faster between teams** if you standardize platform elements like your database layer (*à la* SOA), or provide a standard cross-team architecture (e.g. everyone will emit/consume JSON APIs) that makes it easier to integrate the projects.

Alternatively, you can continue to let people do their own thing in a fully self-organized way, but your schedule will need to accept that **integration between teams will take longer**. The integration itself will likely need an iterative approach to meld the disparate interfaces and platforms that typically emerge from a bottom-up approach.

Comment: I would argue that allowing teams to self-organise would *reduce* the time it takes for integration between teams.

Comment: @BarnabyGolden - why?

Comment: In my experience self organising teams are usually very good at coordination. There tends to be less of a silo mentality and more openness to communication between teams.

Comment: @BarnabyGolden Communications theory holds that 9 teams have 36 communications channels between them, while 15 teams would have 105. And that's just inter-team communication! If you assume a fixed 7-person team size, a 9-team project requires **1,953 communications channels** for full collaboration. This is one of the reasons why scaling agile frameworks can be hard.

Comment: @CodeGnome I never said it was easy! I just said that self organising teams tend to do it well.

Comment: @CodeGnome we have not always seen eye to eye on SE but I am very early in my Agile journey; however I have never come across a post of yours in which I didn't learn something valuable that gave me reflection.  Thanks for this answer.  I suppose I am moving into the HA part of my career and beginning to question more niche aspects of Agile values.